# How to let TableViewCell shadow get outside of tableview

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

[image]I have a view, split in two. There is some buttons in the upper half, and a table view in the lower half. 
The tableView cells have shadows on top and bottom, but I need the shadow of the first cell to be visible in the upper half. the shadow "dissappears" once it touches the tableview top bound, but when I drag the tableview down, the shadow it's there.

This is the code in tableviewcell's awakeFromNib

```
layer.shadowColor = UIColor(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0.25).cgColor
layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 1)
layer.shadowRadius = 3
layer.shadowOpacity = 1
```

I can't post a bigger image for confidentiality terms.
In the image you can see, the white part is the tableView upper bound, and the other color is the rest of the view, and the shadow comes from the cell.

Comment: Add the screenshot of your requirement please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to set the `clipsToBounds` values of the table view and the subviews to false?
Setting clipsToBounds to false means that the subviews (or shadow layers) that are cut out by the original frame of the table view are still shown.
I'd simply try that:

```
tableView.clipsToBounds = false
tableView.contentView.clipsToBounds = false
```

And maybe also do that for the relevant subviews. Good luck! (..and sorry for the slightly inspecific answer, I'm answering from my mobile ;)

Comment: That worked perfectly!
Just with the first line
Thanks!

Comment: No problem, glad to help :)